# Visual Composer Post Grid Custom query Sticky Post issue

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I'm using visual composer by http://vc.wpbakery.com/ on my wordpress site. My issue is within the custom query of the post grid.

I just want to exclude Sticky Posts from the latest cat "ID20" with the query below:-

```
cat=20&posts_per_page=4&offset=0&post_status=publish&ignore_sticky_posts=1
```

But the sticky posts still appear, what did i do wrong?

Comment: Is error still appear in latest version of visual composer?

Comment: Yes, it does. And is there any way to filter only the Sticky post in the Basic Post Grid?